# grid css - position elements on an even row

Tags: css, grid-layout

I am trying to learn the new CSS grid display model, and to do so I have tried to get an hexagonal grid. (Just as an experiment)

I have an example working, but it's quite hacky. I am using **a** elements as placeholders to get the position of the even rows as I want, but overall the system is not much intuitive

```css
body {
  margin: 40px;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 470px;
  eight: 400px;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: 0px repeat(auto-fit, minmax(60px, 1fr));
  background-color: lightgreen;
  color: #444;
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;
  grid-auto-columns: 10px;
  transition: width 6s;
}
.wrapper:hover {
  width: 600px;
}
.box {
  background-color: coral;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 150%;
}
.a {
  grid-column: 1;
  height: 0px;
}
.a:nth-child(even) {
  grid-column-end: span 2;
}
.b {
  margin-top: 28%;
  height: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 57.14%;
  grid-column-end: span 2;
  position: relative;
}
.b:before,
.b:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: coral;
}
.b:before {
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}
.b:after {
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box a">A</div>
  <div class="box a">A</div>
  <div class="box a">A</div>
  <div class="box a">A</div>
  <div class="box a">A</div>
  <div class="box a">A</div>
  <div class="box b">B</div>
  <div class="box b">B</div>
  <div class="box b">B</div>
  <div class="box b">B</div>
  <div class="box b">B</div>
  <div class="box b">B</div>
  <div class="box b">B</div>
  <div class="box b">B</div>
  <div class="box b">B</div>
  <div class="box b">B</div>
  <div class="box b">B</div>
  <div class="box b">B</div>
</div>
```

The alternate way to get this reulst is much less hacky, I have only the elements really needed:

```css
body {
  margin: 40px;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 470px;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(60px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, [odd] auto [even] auto);
  background-color: lightgreen;
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;
  grid-auto-columns: 10px;
  transition: width 6s;
}
.wrapper:hover {
  width: 600px;
}
.box {
  background-color: coral;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 150%;
}
.a {
  height: 0px;
}
.a:nth-child(1) {
  grid-row: even 1;
}
.a:nth-child(2) {
  grid-row: even 2;
}
.a:nth-child(3) {
  grid-row: even 3;
}
.a:nth-child(4) {
  grid-row: even 4;
}
.b {
  margin-top: 28%;
  height: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 57.14%;
  grid-column-end: span 2;
  position: relative;
}
.b:before,
.b:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: coral;
}
.b:before {
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}
.b:after {
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box a">A</div>
  <div class="box a">A</div>
  <div class="box a">A</div>
  <div class="box a">A</div>
  <div class="box b">B</div>
  <div class="box b">B</div>
  <div class="box b">B</div>
  <div class="box b">B</div>
  <div class="box b">B</div>
  <div class="box b">B</div>
  <div class="box b">B</div>
  <div class="box b">B</div>
  <div class="box b">B</div>
  <div class="box b">B</div>
  <div class="box b">B</div>
  <div class="box b">B</div>
</div>
```

But notice that, even though I have multiple rows named **even**, I need to write

```
.a:nth-child(1) {
  grid-row: even 1;
}
.a:nth-child(2) {
  grid-row: even 2;
}
.a:nth-child(3) {
  grid-row: even 3;
}
.a:nth-child(4) {
  grid-row: even 4;
}
```

I some how expected to have a way to automate this.

This doesn't seem a *good* way to do things. Am I missing something that would get this same result, but in a  *cleaner* way ?

**note** I am using Canary to work with - I am not sure about how this snippets show on other browsers. But At this moment I don't care about this, I am just looking for a conceptual solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly doesn't exist, but would be helpful.
You need to preprocess it, say in php or something